# vscode pylance type checking does not recognize re imports

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-typing, pylance, vscode-python

When turning on `"python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "strict"` or `"python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic"`,
`.py` files containing imports of other modules do not recognize reimports and highlight them with errors:

```
"Flow" is not exported from module "prefect"
  Import from "prefect.core" insteadPylancereportPrivateImportUsage
```

where the original module has `__init__.py` but does not contain `__all__` export but does import all the individual objects(in the case above `Flow`). Is there any way of turning that particular setting off in `settings.json` or dealing with muting the error noise?

Answer (score 5):

You can turn this setting off by setting an override in settings.json:

```
  "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportPrivateImportUsage":"none" 
  }
```

You can also set it to "warning" or "information" for less intrusive notifications.